# systemd: Freezing execution in Yocto

Tags: systemd, linux-kernel, yocto-project

We have a legacy device with following configurations:

- Chipset Architecture : Intel NM10 express
- OS : Yocto warrior
- CPU :   Atom D2250 Dual Core
- Volatile Memory : 2GB DDR3
- CPU core : 4

I have generated 64-bit `core-image-sato` and run on my device but `systemd` freezes execution with **SIGILL** (as shown below). **Please note that with 32-bit image the issue is not observed**.

```
systemd[1]: Set hostname to <panther1>.
traps: systemd[1] trap invalid opcode ip:7f257b9b8bd7 sp:7ffe7bc63090 error:0 in libsystemd-shared-241.so[7f257b8b4000+12f000]
systemd[1]: Caught <ILL>, core dump failed (child 77, code=killed, status=4/ILL).
systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
```

I further debugged and found that it happens when`systemd` tries to setup **machineid**. I went through code and functions flow is => `machine_id_setup -> generate_machine_id -> sd_id128_randomize`

**sd_id128_randomize** function consists following lines,

```
/* Set UUID version to 4 --- truly random generation */
id[6] = (id[6] & 0x0F) | 0x40;
/* Set the UUID variant to DCE */
id[8] = (id[8] & 0x3F) | 0x80;
```

**id[6] = (id[6] & 0x0F) | 0x40;** This is the place where execution gets freezes as far as my findings are concerned.

> Any help is really appreciated on why it is happening and how to fix
>   it?

Note : lubuntu is running fine on this device which has systemd in it.

Comment: Did you compile systemd yourself? The signal specifically means a problem in the generated code, not in the source, and I suspect the compiler on your host system assumes it's allowed to use more modern instruction sets than Atom supports...

Comment: I didn't compile systemd myself. You seem to be right. I checked GCC option by `bitbake -e core-image-sato | grep ^TUNE_CCARGS` and the o/p is `TUNE_CCARGS=" -m64 -march=nehalem -mtune=generic -mfpmath=sse -msse4.2"`. I have changed to `-march=atom` and kicked off build.